# JSR-303 and JPA overlapping

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation

Aloha hey!

I already use JPA annotations, now I'd like to use JSR-303 annotations to validate attributes as well.

**My questions is, how well do they interact with each other?**
If I use `@Basic(optional=false)` or `@NotNull`, will I still have to use `nullable=false` etc.?

I haven't decided which validator implementation to use, e.g. hibernate-validator or oVal (You may also suggest others. I know that [oVal is not a JSR-303 implementation, but it maps most annotations](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#d4e187)).

oVal manual (see above) states that certain JPA annotations will be translated into oVal annotations as well. 
Hibernate-validator [has a similar mechanism](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-db).

Some search results claim that Bean Validation and JPA do officially overlap, but I have not figured in which exact way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading both specifications almost entirely, this is what I found.

I'll thusly answer my question myself;
As of now;

- JPA and BV annotations do often share the same meaning.
  The usage of BV constraints however does not influence the created DDL schema constraints of the JPA implementation.
- The JPA implementation will, if configured so, check BV constraints at pre-persist, pre-update, and pre-remove. This is done by delegating the work to the BV implementation. The BV implementation on the other hand will not use JPA constraints.
- Using BV constrains such as `@NotNull` to automatically cause JPA constraints such as `@Column(nullable=false)` is recommended to the JPA implementation in the BV specification, but not part of the official specification and thus not reliable behaviour.

As a result I will have to use both BV and JPA annotations, even though they may have the same meaning.

**References**

- Section 3.6 Bean Validation - [JPA2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).
- Appendix D Java Persistence 2.0 integration - [Bean validation specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/).

*P.S.: I will wait whether someone has any corrections or additions to this, then set is as the preferred answer.*

Comment: Only thing that you added that is different to the other answer >@NotNull to automatically cause JPA constraints is wrong rest is same as other answerer . I am down voting you for answering yourself once answer has been provided and is same as yours (different wording may be)and giving wrong info along the way.

Comment: Well, my question was whether one annotation replaces the need for the other.
Shahzeb only explained under which cirumstances which annotation takes effect. Granted, my answer is mostly the same as his, but it also includes the important bit (3. point in list). Furthermore it explains who is actually doing the validation and when it is done as well as it includes exact references to official specifications.

Answer (score 6):

They are both run time checks . There is some difference though 
JPA specification states `@Basic(optional = false)`  can be use as schema hint i.e if you are updating your database schema by JPA (generally not a good practice though) you can use it to indicate that this column value can not be null and must have a value.

[Section 9.1.18 Basic Annotation of JPA1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

and
[Section 11.1.6 Basic Annotation of JPA2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

Clearly indicate that.

Other than that both will do a runtime check in other words before the sql is send to database.
Generally for validation prior to sending SQL to server if you are using JSR 303 which includes many other checks as well you will use `@NotNull` however you may not be using JSR 303 in which case you can use `@Basic(optional = false)` which has been out even before JSR 303 however is not preferred over JSR303.
You might now want to know `@Column(nullable = false)` is purely used on database side.
Should you ever use both - Yes only if you are allowing JPA to update schema otherwise JSR-303 is preferred over the other.