# Hibernate : Delete child entry using hql

Tags: java, hibernate

Good Day to all,

I have a trouble in hibernate and i am a fresher in hibernate,
i wish to delete a child entry using hql ,
if you have a solution please help me and now i am using pojo classes for creating the entities not xml mapping.

how can give a default value for a table attribute while creating new entity using class mapping (in pojo) not xml mapping

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't use HQL to delete entities, but use `session.delete(entity)`. If you have a cascade remove set on the association (or a cascade all), the the child entity will be deleted along with the parent entity. Read the [hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single) to learn more and see examples.

To specify a default value for a column when generating the schema using Hibernate, you might use the columnDefinition attribute of the [Column](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation. I usually prefer to [generate the database schema by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607683/is-using-jpa-orm-to-generate-a-db-schema-a-bad-idea/7607824#7607824), though.

Comment: I used columnDefinition attribute but after creating db shows descriptions of the attribute as default 'Y' but after inserting data it changed as unambigous symbol like a square